# Построение запрсов в yii

Tags: php, yii

Что-то я сегодня туплю:

Есть массив экземпляров класса Device  -- девайсы доступные юзеру.
Надо получить 20 последних записей из логов.
В sql это выглядит примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM log 
WHERE device_id IN
(SELECT device_id FROM devices WHERE user_id = 2)
ORDER BY log_id DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Как в yii все поля Device->id из массива превратить в строку "IN (1,2,3)" без постройки велосипеда?

**UPDATE:**

Кроме такого ничего в голову не прихоит

```
foreach ($devices as $device)
{
    $devices_id[] = $device->id;
}
$in = implode(',', $devices_id);
```

Вот блин, не уже ли я единственный с таким столкнулся? Доленже быть более лаконичный способ :(

**UPDATE_2:**

Думаю правильная формулировка проблемы:
Получить массив общих свойств из массива объектов.
Но в php нет такой функции. Хотя [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) чем-то похожа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

с данной проблемой сталкивался, обходился так же **implode**, т.е. делал отдельно запрос, получал массив данных, объединял их, и дальше делал запрос:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->
     select('uid')->
     from('link_gu')->
     where('gid in ('.implode(',',$this->arrGroups).')')->
     queryColumn()
```

так же думаю внутрь where, в строке где in вставить готовый sql, вроде должен сработать